# How to change style of the misspelled word indicator in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3

By default misspelled words in Sublime Text 3 (on macOS) are indicated with a wiggly red underline. Is there a way to change it to something else? Like a color background for the word rather than just an underline?

Answer (score 0):

## You can’t change the style of the wiggly lines under misspelled words in macOS but you can disable automatic spelling correction.

Those wiggly lines under misspelled words are part of the macOS finder. Unclear if that can be changed to be a different style.

But you can go into “System Preferences > Keyboard” and then choose the “Text” tab where you have a checkbox option to “Correct spelling automatically” that you can uncheck; see screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the options under “System Preferences > Keyboard”]